# Magento - URL rewriting or redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, url-rewriting

I am running a site in `Magento` version 1.9.1.0 which is `SSL` enabled. When I open that site's admin panel on a browser either after refresh the cache of browser or in private mode then first time it shows site's homepage rather than admin login page i.e. `sitename.com/admin` URL redirects to `https://sitename.com` URL automatically on first time.

Same issue happened when I try to access inner page of the site directly first time.

After this when I enter again URL in browser's address bar as `sitename.com/admin` then it open admin login page which is good on next time(seems cache works).

I am using `Login and Pay with Amazon` extension in my Magento site. So when I go for login with Amazon then after inject the credentials it shows me error as follows:

> **No data received. Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data on chrome.**
>
> **secure connection failed on firefox**

I am using Base URLs (unsecured and secured as https://sitename.com) in admin panel under `System > configuration > General > web` which seems to be right? I have doubt in my `.htaccess` file this part of code. I have used the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}    "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]
```

My Requirements are:

- Site always open with `https` which is working fine.
- When user access the site either with `www` or without `www` site always open with `https://sitename.com`. and avoid `index.php` in the URL which is working fine.
- When I access admin panel at any time either first or next to first, it should display admin login screen.
- Remove error which is occurring after login with Amazon.

Kindly please help me to resolve this issue. If any other code required please let me know.

Comment: It's a known issue with magento, at least up to 1.8 that I know of.  I have a site that does a lot of PR and journalists will just add or remove a www without testing their links, and it means their deep links all end up redirecting to the homepage.  I looked into htaccess fixes a couple years ago and came up empty, and although I know it's hurting these sites most magento devs know about this and don't think it's a big deal.  I hope someone comes up with an answer, it's bugged me for too long

Comment: I would be fine if it redirected `www.example.com/page1` -> `example.com/page1`  that would be ok to use the canonical url and would help with share/+1 counts....but unfortunately it does `www.example.com/page1` -> `example.com` and that isn't good.  Really hope someone has found a fix

Comment: very first time it redirects to home page always. not able to access inner pages directly. I know issue should be in htaccess.

Comment: I think it's complicated by magento's url rewrite system, which isn't just in the htaccess file, there is a table full of rewrites that it references.  It's like that rewrite system can't handle it....whatever the reason is, it is a problem for many magento sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you place in .htaccess the following rewrite, it will bypass this Magento stupidity; apache will rewrite it appropriately before Magento get a chance:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hi @twicejr , can you please help me on this, which is a similar issue, im stuck from past 2 weeks, have placed a bounty for the question too...any help is appreciated...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502192/magento-on-click-of-product-product-detail-page-does-not-work-page-refreshes-i